# Working with files in java

Tags: java, file-io

I have an array of strings.
I want to save those strings in a file.
The problem is, I need to make a new file called db.txt (only if it doesn't exist),
then somehow write strings to it.

And then later I want to be able to read strings from that file and insert them to the array.

Inserting and using array is not the question, but the question is how do I mess with the files? How do I create a new text file (if not existing already), how do I write to it and how do I read from it?

Tried to learn it by myself but I've seen so many ways on the Internet and got confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example of writing to a text file:

```
File file = new File("./db.txt");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file, true); // true for auto-flush
pw.println("Line 1");
pw.println("Line 2");
pw.println("Line 3");
pw.close();
```

In case you want to append to existing text file:

```
File file = new File("./db.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true); // true for appending
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, true); // true for auto-flush
pw.println("Line 4");
pw.println("Line 5");
pw.println("Line 6");
pw.close();
```

To read from text file:

```
File file = new File("./db.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line1 = br.readLine();
String line2 = br.readLine();
String line3 = br.readLine();
br.close();
```

---

Also consider the following:

- [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) does not create new file if it does not exist, while [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) does.
- To check if a file exists, use: [`file.exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29).
- To check if the file object refers to a file or a directory, use: [`file.isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) and [`file.isFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29).
- To create a new file, use: [`file.createNewFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29).
- To create a directory, use: [`file.mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29).
- You may need to use the constructors [`PrintWriter(File file, String csn)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`InputStreamReader(InputStream in, Charset cs)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) to determine the charset.

Comment: Im getting FileNotFoundException. Does it also create the file d.txt for me?

Comment: @Jjang Perhaps you want to read from `db.txt` instead of `d.txt`, as this example does?

Comment: Never heard of `FileWrier`. Is it a new feature of Java7, similar to `FileWriter`?

Comment: Ok, managed to open the file but somehow when I look at the file after I write to it, nothing is written.

Comment: p.s. does it auto create it in the folder of my project?

Comment: @Jjang Did you call `close()`?

Comment: Ok, and how do I check if the file is already exist? I want to create it only once. And next time when I open my program, if it already exist, I won't open it again

Comment: @Jjang Read the points I have written for you to be considered.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to save an array of strings to an file then this is how you do it:

```
public void saveToFile(Iterable<String> stringArray, String pathName) {
    File f = new File(pathName);
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(f);

        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        for (String s : stringArray) {
            bufferedWriter.write(s);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.flush();
        }

        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This snippet assumes that the string array does not contain any newline characters as it is used to seperate each "line" in the file.

```
public Iterable<String> loadFile(String pathName) {
    File f = new File(pathName);

    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);

        String str = scanner.nextLine();

        while (str != null) {
            output.add(str);
            scanner.nextLine();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    return output;
}
```

If you really want the load file method to return a string array then you might need to call the `output.toArray()` method and typecast that to `String[]`.

Answer (score 1):

## Writing to a File and Reading from a file

### Reading from a file

If you want to read from a file, you need to import the `BufferedReader` class from the `java.io.*` package.

Now the `BufferedReader` will take as argument a `FileReader` which in turn will take as argument the name of the file to read from. Let me show you this in code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt"));
```

Now the object `in` can now perform some action on the file `myFile.txt`.
So let's say I wanted the first line in `myFile.txt`: I would use the `readLine()` method.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt"));
String line1 = in.readLine();
```

Now `line1` contains the first line of the file `myfile.txt`.

Let's say you wanted to write the entire lines in a file to an array. All you have to do is use a while loop and the EOF as a sentinel:

```
ArrayList<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt"));
String currentLine = in.readLine();
while(currentLine != null){
    fileLines.add(currentLine);
    currentLine = in.readLine();
}
```

What that does is read every line of the file and write it to an array that can then be used for further processing.

### Writing to files

Here instead of a `BufferedReader` we use a `PrintWriter`, and instead of a `FileReader` we use a `FileWriter`.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter("output.txt"));
```

Now if `output.txt` has not been made beforehand, the program will automatically make a new one.

So let's look at how it prints:

```
String wiseSaying = "This is not a wise saying";
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter("output.txt"));
out.println(wiseSaying);
```

That prints the value of `wiseSaying` to the file `output.txt`.

Now you have to close both files when you are done.

```
in.close();
out.close();
```

If you don't close the out file, you will not see anything in your output file. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To write to a file, use java.io.PrintWriter:

```
    File myFile= new File("db.txt");
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(myFile);
    //Now use out.print() and out.println() just 
    //as you would use System.out.print() and System.out.println()
    out.print("test");
    out.println();
    out.close();
```

To read from a file, use java.io.Scanner:

```
    File myFile = new File("db.txt");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(myFile);
    String n = s.next(); //gets you the next token;
    String n = s.nextLine(); //gets you the next line as a string;
    s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. Managing the file (creating if absent, appending if present)
2. Making sure writing and reading your text is done correctly

---

1) Managing the file

[Note the example assumes Java 6; if using Java 7, you can use the [try-with-resources feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html)]

You will have to check for existence of the file when going to read it. However, when writing the file, you can use the constructor for FileOutputStream that says to append to the file if it exists.

---

2) Reading and writing correctly

For a robust solution, you need to watch out for character encoding issues. The whole Reader/Writer framework was introduced to fix character encoding issues with the Stream implementations (OutputStream/InputStream/etc.).

If you are always going to run the code on systems where the default character encoding is the same, you can get away with using the simple FileWriter/FileReader constructors. However, if you are going to use different OSes with (possibly) different default encodings, you need to specify the encoding to use. To do this, you use the [OutputStreamWriter constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) or [InputStreamReader constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) that takes a stream and a Charset. This allows you to specify the encoding to use.

---

```
package org.foo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FilesAndStrings {

    final static String[] STRINGS = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
    final static String FILE = "strings.txt";
    final static Charset UTF8_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Single argument decides whether we write to the file or read from it
        if (args.length > 0) {
            String[] whatWeRead = readStrings();
            // Do something with whatWeRead
        }
        else {
            writeStrings();
        }
    }

    public static void writeStrings() throws FileNotFoundException {
        OutputStreamWriter out = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(FILE, true), UTF8_CHARSET);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(out);
            pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            for (String s : STRINGS) {
                pw.println(s);
            }
        }
        finally {
            tryToClose(pw);
            tryToClose(bw);
            tryToClose(out);
        }
    }

    public static String[] readStrings() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader in = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FILE), UTF8_CHARSET);
            br = new BufferedReader(in);
            List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
            String s = br.readLine();
            while (s != null) {
                strings.add(s);
                s = br.readLine();
            }
            return strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
        }
        finally {
            tryToClose(br);
            tryToClose(in);
        }
    }

    public static void tryToClose(final Writer w) {
        try {
            w.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // Log error
        }
    }

    public static void tryToClose(final Reader r) {
        try {
            r.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // Log error
        }
    }
}
```

---