# Java-Compare username and password with text File

Tags: java

Currently I am working on a program that required to add multiple user and each user will have their own password, so all the username and password will save on a same text file. My question is, is there any solution to just comparing the username and password and that it.

For example, User A login, after the user type in the Username and Password it will go through the text file and take out User A username and password without touching User B or C Username and password of user B or C

Comment: You really, *really* shouldn't be storing the passwords in a file.

Comment: And if you are, you should at least be hashing them.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017688/what-is-the-best-practice-for-securely-storing-passwords-in-java

Comment: Is it `Swing`? Or a Web App? In case of a Web App you should use a Database, for `Swing` maybe the file is good but you should try [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), take a look at [`ArrayLists`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) too or also take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046445/working-with-files-in-java)

Comment: also you might want to use `Serializable` classes, and for better help sooner please post a [Minimal Complete and Verifiaable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) C: Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is using `Properties`. A Java-Properties-File look like this:

```
# this is a comment
name=value
user=password
```

I would recommend to not store the password as plain-text in your file. Saving it's hash will be enough to compare passwords:

```
public class YourPasswordStorage
{
    Properties users = new Properties();

    public YourPasswordStorage (File file)
    {
       user.load(file);
    }

    void insertUser (String user, String password)
    {
        users.put(user,
            Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
                MessageDigest.getInstance("sha-512").digest(password)));
    }

    boolean checkUser (String user, String password)
    {
        String hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
            MessageDigest.getInstance("sha-512").digest(password));
        return (hash.equals(users.get(user)); // note that users.get(user) could be null
    }
}
```

Note that the Code above won't compile because of some uncaught Exceptions, but I hope you understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Storing raw passwords in a text file isn't very safe for your users. It's a lot better to salt your passwords first - systematically convert them into hash that you write to file. Then instead of comparing password to password, you take salt the password the user gives you and compare that to what's written to file. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/suggestions-for-library-to-hash-passwords-in-java) (and many other places) for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard *NEVER GIVE A MONKEY TO DO MAN'S WORK*

Well AFAICS you will have the fields `username password and user` so why dont use a `database` instead of a file.
Take advantage of `H2 database` allows you to store data as file.
Just include the `driver jar` and write this simple codes

```
Connection con = null;
try{
   Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./mydb;MODE=MySQL;", "", "");
   PreparedStatement stmt= con.prepareStatement
            ("INSERT INTO  yourTable(user,username,password) VALUES(?,?,?)");
   stmt.setString(1, "someUser");
   stmt.setString(2, "someUsername");
   stmt.setString(3, "somePassword");
   stmt.executeUpdate();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
//close statements
}
```